# Maintain the scroll position of a listview after getting new data

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview that after refreshing it and getting new data. It goes to the top of the listview and not where I last scrolled it to.

I have set a timer that after 2 seconds, it gets new data and puts it into the listview.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :D

Here is the Mainactivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    getJSON();

    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3500);
} 

 private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        getJSON();

        handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
    }
};

private void showEmployee(){
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

        for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = jo.getString(Config.TAG_ID);
            String name = jo.getString(Config.TAG_NAME);

            HashMap<String,String> employees = new HashMap<>();
            employees.put(Config.TAG_ID,id);
            employees.put(Config.TAG_NAME,name);
            list.add(employees);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            MainActivity.this, list, R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{Config.TAG_ID,Config.TAG_NAME},
            new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name});

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

 private void getJSON(){
    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            JSON_STRING = s;
            showEmployee();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String s = rh.sendGetRequest(Config.URL_GET_ALL);
            return s;
        }
    }
    GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
    gj.execute();
}
```

Comment: just notify adapter for changes.

Comment: check out more about transcriptMode in listview attributes

Comment: why upvoting ? reason

Answer (score 1):

in onCreate() initialize your adapter with empty list and bind with listView.
make your adapter and list global in class.

now whenever you add data to adapter just call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

this is how it also works in fragment.

Answer (score 1):

The `ListView` is scrolled to the top because the `Adapter` is set again. Instead of setting the `Adapter` each time new data is recieved, you can simply add the new data to the already existing `List`/dataset and call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on the `ListView`'s `Adapter`. The `ListView`'s position wont change.

Answer (score 0):

To restore the scroll position use this.

```
    Parcelable state;

     @Override
   public void onPause() {    
  // Save ListView state @ onPause
  Log.d(TAG, "saving listview state @ onPause");
   state = listView.onSaveInstanceState();
  super.onPause();
}
```

...

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
// Set new items
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
...
 // Restore previous state (including selected item index and scroll        position)
 if(state != null) {
    Log.d(TAG, "trying to restore listview state..");
    listView.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your listview's onScrollListner get the position of your last visible item and when you load more data, set listview's setSelection

```
int ScrollPos=0;

listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int threshold = 1;
            int count = listview.getCount();
            if (listViewList1.size() >= YOUR LOAD ELEMENTS SIZE(Everytime))
                if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    if (listview.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count
                            - threshold) {
                        scrollPos = listViewList.size();
                        // Execute LoadMoreDataTask AsyncTask

                    }
                }
        }
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

and while again fetching more data just call Listview.setSelection(scrollPos)
and for the first time just manage to set you scrollpos back to 0
hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You must declare the adapter and the list as instance variables instead of declaring them locally. Whenever there is any change in data, you must do the respection update operation on the list and then call adapter's notifyDataSetChanged() method to update the listview.

Change your code to this :

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;
ListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();//changed
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    MainActivity.this, list, R.layout.list_item,
    new String[]{Config.TAG_ID,Config.TAG_NAME},
    new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name});//changed

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

getJSON();

handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3500);
} 

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {

    getJSON();

    handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
}
};

private void showEmployee(){
JSONObject jsonObject = null;
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
try {
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
    JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

    for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
        JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
        String id = jo.getString(Config.TAG_ID);
        String name = jo.getString(Config.TAG_NAME);

        HashMap<String,String> employees = new HashMap<>();
        employees.put(Config.TAG_ID,id);
        employees.put(Config.TAG_NAME,name);
        list.add(employees);
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//changed

}

private void getJSON(){
class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        JSON_STRING = s;
        showEmployee();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
        String s = rh.sendGetRequest(Config.URL_GET_ALL);
        return s;
    }
}
GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
gj.execute();
}
```